# Rewriting a binomial coefficient in terms of Pochhammer symbols

Tags: binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

I am working with the equation
$$ \sum^{2n+1}_{k=0} \binom{2n+1}{k}(x^k -(-x)^k), \ n = 0,1,2,..$$ and want to rewrite it in terms of rising Pochhammer symbols.

I am aware of the relation
$$ \frac{(x)_n}{n!} = \binom{x+n-1}{n}.$$ But how could I manipulate my binomial coefficient to get it in to this form?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Just to clarify, here we denote $(x)_n$ as the rising factorial i.e $x(x+1)(x+2)\dots(x+n-1)$

Comment: Since $$\frac{(x)_k}{k!} = \binom{x+k-1}{k}$$ then just solve for $x$ in $x+k-1=2n+1$ to get the argument of your Pochhammer symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We can write
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{2n+1}{k}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n)\cdots(2n-k+2)}{k!}=\frac{(2n-k+2)_k}{k!}
> \end{align*}

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Sorry for this inconvenience and thanks for upvote. :-)